# C++: First function creates object, then second function takes that object as a parameter - How?

Tags: c++, function, oop, parameters

Ok, I know my title is very unclear but I think part of the problem is that I don't know how to explain it clearly enough for Google to be useful.

Basically I have two functions:

```
    SentenceData parseSingleSentence(std::string inputString)
    {
        SentenceData actualSentenceData;

        actualSentenceData.transmitter = inputString.substr(1, 2);
        actualSentenceData.format = inputString.substr(3, 3);

        // Data fields run from first ',' (index 7) and the last 3 characters can be disregarded
        std::stringstream ss(inputString.substr(7, inputString.length()-10));
        std::string newDataField;
        while (!ss.eof()) {
            getline(ss, newDataField, ',');
            actualSentenceData.dataFields.push_back(newDataField);
        }

        return actualSentenceData;
    }

    bool hasCorrectNumberOfFields(SentenceData sentenceData)
    {
        std::map<std::string, int>::iterator iterator = supportedFormats.begin();
        while (iterator != supportedFormats.end())
        {
            if (sentenceData.format == iterator->first && int(sentenceData.dataFields.size()) == iterator->second) return true;
            ++iterator;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

In my main(), I would like to run:

```
    parseSingleSentence(inputString);
    if (!hasCorrectNumberOfFields(actualSentenceData)) continue;
```

However, there is a clear problem - the compiler doesn't recognise that actualSentenceData will be returned after parseSingleSentence() is called.

The error is:
376:43: Use of undeclared identifier 'actualSentenceData'

I was originally expecting the compiler to recognise that the appropriate variable would be returned by the first function. When it threw up the error I quickly realised the problem but don't understand what the solution could be.

Is there a fix for this? I've spent several hours trying to find out what I've missed and don't know where to go from here.

I've searched on Google and Stack Overflow. Plus looked through several C++ websites, watched some tutorials, and my lectures from university.

Comment: You never receive the value from `parseSingleSentence(inputString);` to store it in a variable.

Comment: On a side note: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/) Inside of `parseSingleSentence()`, the loop `while (!ss.eof()) { getline(ss, newDataField, ','); ... }` should be `while (getline(ss, newDataField, ',')) { ... }` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *capture* the return value in another variable (which you can call anything you like, here I called it `sd`).

```
SentenceData sd = parseSingleSentence(inputString);
if (!hasCorrectNumberOfFields(sd)) continue;
```

Local variables only exist in the function they are declared in, `return` doesn't change that. What is returned from a function is a *value* not a variable. If you want to save that value you need another variable.

Comment: John, you are a star, thank you so much. Such a simple thing but so difficult to articulate!

Comment: Just mentioning that `if (!hasCorrectNumberOfFields(parseSingleSentence(inputString))) continue;` would work as well.

Answer (score 2):

I guess u mean smth like that:

```cpp
SentenceData data = parseSingleSentence(inputString);
if (!hasCorrectNumberOfFields(data)) { 
  continue;
}
```

Additionally:

1. Its considered good to reduce the variable scope, so if u use modern C++ standards, u can use the following optionally:

```
if (auto data = parseSingleSentence(inputString); !hasCorrectNumberOfFields(data)) {
  continue;
}
```

2. The parameter in `hasCorrectNumberOfFields` is taken by value, u would better to use `const&` or pass it by value and use `std::move(data)` when calling it, if `SentenceData` has a move constructor.
3. U'd better replacing `while` loop with `range-based-for`:

```
bool hasCorrectNumberOfFields(SentenceData sentenceData) {
  for (const auto& [format, fields]: supportedFormats) {
    if (sentenceData.format == format && 
        (int)sentenceData.dataFields.size() == fields) 
    { 
       return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```